# How to find$\sum_{i,j,k\in \mathbb{Z}}\binom{n}{i+j}\binom{n}{j+k}\binom{n}{i+k}$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

Yeah, it's
$$\sum_{i,j,k\in \mathbb{Z}}\binom{n}{i+j}\binom{n}{j+k}\binom{n}{i+k}$$
and we are summing over all possible triplets of integers. It appears quite obvious that result is not an infinity. I tried to calculate
$$\sum_{i,j \in \mathbb{Z}} \binom{n}{i+j}\sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} \binom{n}{i+k} \binom{n}{j+k}$$
but it doesn't get easier for me. My intuition says that we are calculating something over set of size $3n$, but i couldn't get any idea right.
I'd appreciate some help on this super old exam task.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The key is given any $(u,v,w) \in \mathbb{Z}^3$, one can find
$(i,j,k) \in \mathbb{Z}^3$ such that
$$\begin{cases}
u &= i + j,\\
v &= j + k,\\
w &= k + i
\end{cases}$$
when and only when $u + v + w$ is even. Furthermore, the $(i,j,k)$ associated to $(u,,v,w)$ is unique if it exists. This leads to

$$
 \sum_{i,j,k \in \mathbb{Z}}\binom{n}{i+j}
\binom{n}{j+k}\binom{n}{k+i}
= \sum_{\substack{u,v,w \in \mathbb{Z},\\ u+v+w\text{ even}}}
\binom{n}{u}\binom{n}{v}\binom{n}{w}
= \sum_{\substack{0 \le u, v, w \le n\\ u+v+w\text{ even}}}
\binom{n}{u}\binom{n}{v}\binom{n}{w}\\
= \frac12 \sum_{0 \le u, v, w \le n}\left(1 + (-1)^{u+v+w}\right)\binom{n}{u}\binom{n}{v}\binom{n}{w}
= \frac12\left\{\left[\sum_{u=0}^n \binom{n}{u}\right]^3
+ \left[\sum_{u=0}^n (-1)^u\binom{n}{u}\right]^3
\right\}\\
= \frac12\left[(1+1)^{3n} + (1-1)^{3n}\right]
\stackrel{\color{blue}{[1]}}{=} \frac12 \left[2^{3n} + \begin{cases}0,& n > 0\\1,&n = 0\end{cases}\right]
= \begin{cases}2^{3n-1},&n > 0\\1, &n = 0\end{cases}
$$

**Notes**

- $\color{blue}{[1]}$ - thanks for @FelixMartin pointing out the special case at $n = 0$.

Comment: This trick with moving constraint $2|u+v+w$ inside a sum is really smart! That's a great trick.

Comment: @achillehui: Very nice! (+1)

Comment: Or, after making the initial observation, one can simply observe that the sum counts the even-sized subsets of $[3n]$, of which there are $2^{3n-1}$ if $n>0$. (If $n=0$ there is of course $1$.)

Comment: You're welcome. It's a quite nice answer.

Answer (score 5):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\,{#1}\,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,\mathrm{Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> \begin{equation}
> \mathbf{\mbox{The Question:}\quad}
> \sum_{j,k,\ell\ \in\ \mathbb{Z}}\,\,
> {n \choose j + k}{n \choose k + \ell}{n \choose j + \ell} =\ ?\tag{1}
> \end{equation}

---

\begin{equation}\mbox{Note that}\
\sum_{j,k,\ell\ \in\ \mathbb{Z}}\,\,
{n \choose j + k}{n \choose k + \ell}{n \choose j + \ell}=
\sum_{j,k\ \in\ \mathbb{Z}}\,\,
{n \choose j + k}\
\overbrace{\sum_{\ell\ \in\ \mathbb{Z}}{n \choose k + \ell}
{n \choose j + \ell}}^{\ds{\equiv\ \,\mathcal{I}}}\tag{2}
\end{equation}

---

\begin{align}
\fbox{$\ds{\ \,\mathcal{I}\ }$} & =
\sum_{\ell\ \in\ \mathbb{Z}}{n \choose k + \ell}{n \choose j + \ell} =
\sum_{\ell\ \in\ \mathbb{Z}}{n \choose k + \ell}{n \choose n - j - \ell}
\\[4mm] & =
\sum_{\ell\ \in\ \mathbb{Z}}{n \choose k + \ell}\oint_{\verts{z} = 1^{-}}
{\pars{1 + z}^{n} \over z^{n - j - \ell + 1}}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic} =
\oint_{\verts{z} = 1^{-}}
{\pars{1 + z}^{n} \over z^{n - j + 1}}
\sum_{\ell\ \in\ \mathbb{Z}}{n \choose k + \ell}z^{\ell}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[4mm] & =
\oint_{\verts{z} = 1^{-}}
{\pars{1 + z}^{n} \over z^{n - j + k + 1}}
\sum_{\ell\ \in\ \mathbb{Z}}{n \choose \ell}z^{\ell}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[4mm] & =
\oint_{\verts{z} = 1^{-}}{\pars{1 + z}^{n} \over z^{n - j + k + 1}}
\pars{1 + z}^{n}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic} = {2n \choose n - j + k} =
{2n \choose n + j - k}
\\[4mm] & =
\fbox{$\ds{\ \oint_{\verts{z} = 1^{-}}
{\pars{1 + z}^{2n} \over z^{n + j - k + 1}}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}\ }$} =
\fbox{$\ds{\ \,\mathcal{I}\ }$}
\end{align}

---

The original summation $\ds{\pars{1}}$ is reduced to $\pars{~\mbox{see expression}\ \pars{2}~}$:
\begin{align}
&\color{#f00}{\sum_{j,k,\ell\ \in\ \mathbb{Z}}\,\,
{n \choose j + k}{n \choose k + \ell}{n \choose j + \ell}} =
\sum_{j,k\ \in\ \mathbb{Z}}{n \choose j + k}\oint_{\verts{z} = 1^{-}}
{\pars{1 + z}^{2n} \over z^{n + j - k + 1}}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[4mm] = &\
\sum_{j\ \in\ \mathbb{Z}}\,\,\oint_{\verts{z} = 1^{-}}
{\pars{1 + z}^{2n} \over z^{n + j + 1}}
\sum_{k\ \in\ \mathbb{Z}}{n \choose j + k}z^{k}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic} =
\sum_{j\ \in\ \mathbb{Z}}\,\,\oint_{\verts{z} = 1^{-}}
{\pars{1 + z}^{2n} \over z^{n + 2j + 1}}
\sum_{k\ \in\ \mathbb{Z}}{n \choose k}z^{k}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[4mm] = &\
\sum_{j\ \in\ \mathbb{Z}}\,\,\oint_{\verts{z} = 1^{-}}
{\pars{1 + z}^{3n} \over z^{n + 2j + 1}}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic} =
\sum_{j\ \in\ \mathbb{Z}}{3n \choose n + 2j} =
\sum_{j\ \in\ \mathbb{Z}}{3n \choose n + j}\,{1 + \pars{-1}^{j} \over 2}
\\[4mm] = &\
\half\sum_{j\ \in\ \mathbb{Z}}{3n \choose j} +
\half\,\pars{-1}^{n}\sum_{j\ \in\ \mathbb{Z}}{3n \choose j}\pars{-1}^{j} =
\half\,\pars{1 + 1}^{3n} + \half\,\pars{-1}^{n}\pars{1 - 1}^{3n}
\\[4mm] = &\
\color{#f00}{2^{3n - 1} + \half\,\delta_{n0}}
\end{align}

Comment: Upvoted. (+1). Always nice to see the Egorychev method put in an appearance.

Comment: @MarkoRiedel Thanks a lot. This method is quite nice.

Comment: I try to promote it whenever I can. While we have to say that the Cauchy Residue Theorem has been a favorite for many mathematicians working in the field it was your posts at MSE that alerted me to this powerful method. I hope you get more votes, you certainly deserve them.

Comment: @MarkoRiedel A 'counting ( combinatoric ) method' is always welcome. However,  one of my old teacher says 'to count is quite difficult". I like a lot the $\mbox{@André Nicolas}, \mbox{Jack D'Aurizio}, \mbox{@Joriki}, \mbox{@Robert Israel}$, etc$\ldots$ answers which are always in the 'counting side'. However, this method is straightforward but it does not yield a 'feeling' like the 'counting one'.

Comment: The advantage of the Egorychev method is its strongly algorithmic aspect.  Some day someone will implement it in a CAS and there will be no more posts for MSE regulars to solve! ;-)